# Convert integer to string with C++ compatible function for Matlab Coder

Tags: string, matlab, type-conversion, matlab-coder

I'm using **Matlab Coder** to convert some Matlab code to C++, however I'm having trouble converting intergers to strings.

`int2str()` is not supported for code generation, so I must find some other way to convert ints to strings. I've tried googling it, without success. Is this even possible?

Comment: Is `num2str` supported? It's the most general function of this type.

Comment: num2str is unfortunately not supported either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done manually (very painful, though)

```
function s = thePainfulInt2Str( n )
s = '';
is_pos = n > 0; % //save sign
n = abs(n); %// work with positive
while n > 0
    c = mod( n, 10 ); % get current character
    s = [uint8(c+'0'),s]; %// add the character
    n = ( n -  c ) / 10; %// "chop" it off and continue
end
if ~is_pos
    s = ['-',s]; %// add the sign
end
```

Comment: I think you need to change the `while` condition to `n>0`

Comment: Minor nit, this prints an incorrect string for `intmin` of the signed integer types since `abs(n)` will saturate. For example `abs(intmin('int32'))` will saturate so that `-intmax('int32')` is printed. Could add a check for `intmin` and then add one to `s(end)`.

Answer (score 7):

[**`sprintf`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) is another very basic function, so it possibly works in C++ as well:

```
x = int64(1948)
str = sprintf('%i',x)
```

It is also the underlying function used by `int2str`.

---

According to this [**comprehensive list of supported functions**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html), as pointed out by Matt in the comments, `sprintf` is not supported, which is surprising. However there is the undocumented helper function (therefore not in the list) [**`sprintfc`**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) which seems to work and can be used equivalently:

```
str = sprintfc('%i',x)
```

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Before writing an answer, I checked the list [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html) and `sprintf` does not seem to be supported.

Comment: sprintf is not supported either.

Comment: @ein123 how about the undocumented `sprintfc` - can you check?

Comment: sprintfc actually seems to work. I guess that is the smoothest solution then. Thanks! @thewaywewalk

Comment: Actually I found out now that `sprintfc` does not work. It didn't warn at first, for some reason, but now it does. So I suppose you have to do this manually. @thewaywewalk

Comment: @ein123 good to know! You should consider accepting Shai's Answer than, as that one helped you.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As of MATLAB R2018a, `sprintf` is supported for code generation by MATLAB Coder.

**Pre R2018a Answer**

You could also call the C runtime `sprintf` or `snprintf` using `coder.ceval`. This has the benefit of making supporting floating point inputs easy as well. You can also change the formatting as desired by tweaking the format string.

Supposing that your compiler provides `snprintf` one could use:

```
function s = cint2str(x)
%#codegen
if coder.target('MATLAB')
    s = int2str(x);
else
    coder.cinclude('<stdio.h>');
    assert(isfloat(x) || isinteger(x), 'x must be a float or an integer');
    assert(x == floor(x) && isfinite(x), 'x must be a finite integer value');
    if isinteger(x)
        switch class(x)
            % Set up for Win64, change to match your target
            case {'int8','int16','int32'}
                fmt = '%d';
            case 'int64'
                fmt = '%lld';
            case {'uint8','uint16','uint32'}
                fmt = '%u';
            otherwise
                fmt = '%llu';
        end
    else
        fmt = '%.0f';
    end
    % NULL-terminate for C
    cfmt = [fmt, 0];

    % Set up external C types
    nt = coder.opaque('int','0');
    szt = coder.opaque('size_t','0');
    NULL = coder.opaque('char*','NULL');

    % Query length
    nt = coder.ceval('snprintf',NULL,szt,coder.rref(cfmt),x);
    n = cast(nt,'int32');
    ns = n+1;  % +1 for trailing null

    % Allocate and format
    s = coder.nullcopy(blanks(ns));
    nt = coder.ceval('snprintf',coder.ref(s),cast(ns,'like',szt),coder.rref(cfmt),x);
    assert(cast(nt,'int32') == n, 'Failed to format string');
end
```

Note that you'll possibly need to tweak the format string to match the hardware on which you're running since this assumes that `long long` is available and maps 64-bit integers to it.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following workaround to enable `sprintf` for general use with Matlab Coder:

1) Create the following m-file named "sprintf.m", preferably in a folder NOT on your Matlab path:

```
function s = sprintf(f, varargin)

if (coder.target('MATLAB'))
    s = builtin('sprintf',f,varargin{:});
elseif (coder.target('MEX'))
    s = builtin('sprintf',f,varargin{:});
else
    coder.cinclude('stdio.h');
    s = char(zeros(1024,1));
    cf = [f,0]; % NULL-terminated string for use in C
    coder.ceval('sprintf_s', coder.ref(s(1)), int32(1024), coder.rref(cf(1)), varargin{:});
end
```

2) Ensure that `sprintf` is not specified as extrinsic via `coder.extrinsic`

3) Specify the folder containing the newly created "sprintf.m" as additional include directory when generating code. If you use the `codegen` function, this can be done via the `-I` switch. If you use the Coder App, this can be done under "More Settings -> Custom Code -> Additional include directories" from the "Generate" tab.

4) Convert from int to string as follows: `s=sprintf('%d',int32(n));`

Notes:

- The specified "sprintf.m" shadows the built-in `sprintf` function and executes instead of the built-in function every time you call `sprintf` from generated code. By placing this file in a folder that is not on the Matlab path, you avoid calling it from other code made to run in Matlab. The `coder.target` call also helps to navigate back to the built-in function in case this gets called in a normal Matlab session or from a MEX file.
- The code above limits the result to 1023 characters (a terminating zero is required at the end). The call to `sprintf_s` instructs the C++ compiler to throw a runtime exception if the result exceeds this value. This prevents memory corruption that is often only caught much later and is harder to trace back to the offending call. This limit can be modified to your own requirements.
- Numeric types must be cast to the correct class before passing them to `sprintf`, e.g. cast to `int32` to match a `%d` in the format string. This requirement is the same when using `fprintf` with Matlab Coder. However, in the `fprintf` case, Matlab Coder catches type errors for you. For `sprintf`, the C++ compiler may fail or the resulting string may contain errors.
- String arguments must be NULL-terminated manually to be used in C calls, as Matlab Coder does not do this automatically (credit to Ryan Livingston for pointing this out). The code above ensures that the format string `f` is NULL-terminated, but NULL-termination of other string arguments remains the responsibility of the calling function.
- This code was tested on a Windows platform with a Visual Studio C++ compiler and Matlab R2016a (Matlab Coder 3.1), but is expected to work in most other environments as well.

Comment: Don't forget to null-terminate any arguments which will be C strings: `cf = [f, 0]; coder.ceval(...,coder.rref(cf(1)));`. MATLAB Coder produced character arrays are not null-terminated. Failing to do so will result in undefined behavior in the generated code.